How do I use the BLE on my phone to connect to my Segway gen 3 iot device to unlock my scooter
I can't connect to  or send unlock or any commands to my Segway gen 3 iot device I can't use or control my scooter without making this stupid thing work or unlock please help
Ive tried using almost ever ble terminal scanner  app i can find ive done Everything I could think and nothing happens

you need to provide some code that can reproduce your problem

And here is an example of how to do it:
https://github.com/AndrewDongminYoo/segway-ble-manager

How do i use thehttps://github.com/AndrewDongminYoo/segway-ble-manager info

If im being asked for the encrypted dataof the previous crc8 checksum value how do i get that info

5AA50230200278010025FF ok so how do i convert this i to ble hex
